# JSON transformation -jq

Tags: json, jq

I am looking to transform a json response from an API call. I came across 'jq' and experimented with it, but it kept getting out of hand; was unable to get the desired output.

**Sample Input JSON:**

```
{
    "realtime": {
        "status": {
            "name": "realtime",
            "link": {
                "state": "RUNNING",
                "link_id": "09-1"
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "state": "RUNNING",
                    "link_id": "09-1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "state": "STOPPED",
                    "link_id": "09-1"
                }
            ],
            "doc": "origin"
        }
    },
    "cmx": {
        "status": {
            "name": "cmx",
            "link": {
                "state": "RUNNING",
                "link_id": "09-1"
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "state": "FAILED",
                    "link_id": "09-1",
                    "log": "ErrorMsg"
                }
            ],
            "doc": "origin"
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected JSON Output:**

```
{
    "realtime.0": {
        "name": "realtime",
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "url": "/link/realtime/",
        "item": 0,
        "item_state": "RUNNING",
        "item_url": "/links/realtime/items/0/"
    },
    "realtime.1": {
        "name": "realtime",
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "url": "/link/realtime/",
        "item": 1,
        "item_state": "STOPPED",
        "item_url": "/links/realtime/items/1/"x
    },
    "cmx.0": {
        "name": "cmx",
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "url": "/links/cmx/",
        "item": 0,
        "item_state": "FAILED",
        "item_url": "/links/cmx/items/0/",
        "log": "ErrorMsg"
    }
}
```

The best I got was with command below:
`.[]|.status | .name as $name |.link.state as $state| .items[] | {$name, $state,items:[.]}| del(.items[].link_id)`

**Which resulted in below (not even close):**

```
{
  "name": "realtime",
  "state": "RUNNING",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "RUNNING"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "name": "realtime",
  "state": "RUNNING",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "state": "STOPPED"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "name": "cms",
  "state": "RUNNING",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "FAILED",
      "log": "Error"
    }
  ]
}
```

Appreciate the help.
Also, it will very helpful in understanding the solution if an explanation to the steps / filters applied is given.

Thanks!!

Comment: @pmf - Thanks! You made it look easy. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/U8sqb9QKtmI) -To remove nulls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one straightforward way using `with_entries`, which lets you manipulate the `.key` and `.value` fields for each item. Here, we store (iterate over) the items of the `.status.items` array in a variable, and piece together all the fields needed, either from the current `.value` (context) or from the current `$item` (variable).

```bash
with_entries(
  .value.status.items[] as $item
  | .key += ".\($item.id)"
  | .value |= {
      name: .status.name,
      state: .status.link.state,
      url: "/link/\(.status.name)/",
      item: $item.id,
      item_state: $item.state,
      item_url: "/link/\(.status.name)/items/\($item.id)/",
      log: $item.log
  }
)
```

```json
{
  "realtime.0": {
    "name": "realtime",
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "url": "/link/realtime/",
    "item": 0,
    "item_state": "RUNNING",
    "item_url": "/link/realtime/items/0/",
    "log": null
  },
  "realtime.1": {
    "name": "realtime",
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "url": "/link/realtime/",
    "item": 1,
    "item_state": "STOPPED",
    "item_url": "/link/realtime/items/1/",
    "log": null
  },
  "cmx.0": {
    "name": "cmx",
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "url": "/link/cmx/",
    "item": 0,
    "item_state": "FAILED",
    "item_url": "/link/cmx/items/0/",
    "log": "ErrorMsg"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PN9eWhcgouf)

Comment: nice solution ... what is the most effective way not to add `"log": null` to the first two entries?

Comment: @jpseng I subsumed that under "straightforward" :) A quick yet "hacky" way would be to delete it afterwards if it meets the conditions: `.value |= ({…} | del(.log | nulls))`